# PHPMailer send mail but it is not delivered

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an e-mail using PHPMailer. Here is my code:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->From = 'login@interia.pl';
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email']);
$mail->Host = "poczta.interia.pl";
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "login@interia.pl";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
$mail->AddAddress ("login@interia.pl",""); 
if($mail->Send()) echo 'E-mail sent';
else echo 'Error! E-mail not sent';
```

The problem is that it says that e-mail was sent but I'm receiving nothing in my inbox.

Comment: Receiving a SMTP success code means that the sender completed the try. It doesn't necessarily mean that the receipient will get the mail.

There are many things to consider: Spam? DKIM? Downtime? Delays? Policies?  [...]

Comment: Did you check spam?

Comment: Yes, nothing's there